# SPI_IIC_LCD library on Arduino

Tags: arduino, lcd

```
SPI_IIC_LCD/MCP23008.cpp:23:28: error: call of overloaded ‘write(int)’ is ambiguous
```

If you get this type of error when trying to compile the SPI_IIC_LCD library for arduino 1.0 you need to edit MCP23008.cpp and insert (uint8_t) where Wire.write is called like so:

```
Wire.write((uint8_t)0x00);
```

I took me a while to figure out, hopefully i can save someone some time by posting this.

Comment: Self-answering questions is great and encouraged on Stack Overflow, but please make sure to split the post into a question and an answer part. Thanks for the info anyway!

Comment: Fair enough, will do in the future :)